# Array of interface undefined after assigning result of .subscribe to it

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular 7 application that I'm working on and I'm trying to assign the value of an HTTP get call to a variable in a component.  The call is to return and Item[] which is an interface in my application and assign it to a local variable in my component which is also of type Item[].  The observable returns the data fine but after the assignment is attempted the local variable remains undefined.

I've tried to define my local variable as `item: Item[]` as well as `item: Item[] = []`.

I'm using a resolver to call my service (works as expected)

```
@Injectable()
export class ShopItemResolver implements Resolve<Item[]> {
    constructor(private shopSvc: ShopService, private router: Router,
                private alertify: AlertifyService) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<Item[]> {
        return this.shopSvc.getItems().pipe(
            catchError(error => {
                this.alertify.error('Problem retrieving shop items');
                this.router.navigate(['/home']);
                return of(null);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Code from my service that calls an API (works as expected)

```
getItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
    return this.http.get<Item[]>(this.appBase + 'inventory/items');
  }
```

Here is my component that is making use of the activated route to get the data.

```
items: Item[];

  constructor(private shopSvc: ShopService, private alertify: AlertifyService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.items = data.items;
    });
   }
```

I'm expecting `this.items = data.items` to result in `this.items` being populated with data from the subscription but it's remaining undefined.

My result from the subscription in data.items looks like this

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "M5RDENDIEMVQDNT7ZBSDILES", name: "Black Shirt", description: "test shirt", categoryId: "WWVHETDEBLZMC56CXRLXHQD3", categoryName: "Men's Clothing", …}
1: {id: "AQ4QSJBZAXSLFYMM5OUVMN5S", name: "White shirt", description: "test white shirt", categoryId: "WWVHETDEBLZMC56CXRLXHQD3", categoryName: "Men's Clothing", …}
2: {id: "J2BUKL5ISUES7MG4HX6AS5YA", name: "leather bracelet", description: "test bracelet", categoryId: "NDDQF73XMP2ZYSMSPIMC5MVT", categoryName: "Jewelry", …}
3: {id: "VX24EA6FUSUQAPYND5WKXEZH", name: "Wallet", description: "test wallet", categoryId: "6LNWE4A6MKX3H4ZKBCPDEU3E", categoryName: "Wallets", …}
4: {id: "FPLFHLVWSXOQWVB3K73YZYAT", name: "grey shirt", description: "test womens shirt", categoryId: "FDPF5P2V3FJGSGTYUBC2QHYC", categoryName: "Women's Clothing", …}
5: {id: "7HQV75KL6CSXEPH3KLCO6QCK", name: "red shirt", description: "test womens shirt", categoryId: "FDPF5P2V3FJGSGTYUBC2QHYC", categoryName: "Women's Clothing", …}
```

This is the Item interface

```
    export interface Item {
        Id: string;
        Name: string;
        Description: string;
        CategoryId: string;
        CategoryName: string;
        Price: number;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your route definition for this component?

Comment: plz try to debug the code and have a look How it's running, I think it will run the template before subscribe is finished

Comment: @KenanaReda In the debugger at the time of the assignment data.items is populated with data successfully.  When stepping over that call this.items is undefined.  If i use ```somevariable: any;``` it works fine.

Comment: @KenanaRada that is the case, but not the problem. He already said he tried to declare the item as `items:Item[] = []` - it should not be undefined at first in this case. It is more likely that the data is not what you'd expect. @ZahiE try logging the "data" Object in your subscribe block. I will most likely look different to what you expect it to be.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment route is just an activated route (import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';).  It's the result of the injectable class you see above.

Comment: @pascalpuetz please see the additions to my post above.

Comment: @ZahiE This might be a timing problem with your console. Try printing it with `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`. It has to be undefined at this point.

Comment: @pascalpuetz the result is what I expect unless i have a problem somewhere 
{
 "items":
 [
  {"id":"M5RDENDIEMVQDNT7ZBSDILES","name":"Black Shirt","description":"test shirt","categoryId":"WWVHETDEBLZMC56CXRLXHQD3","categoryName":"Men's Clothing","price":30},
 ]
}

Comment: I replaced the assignment call completely with the suggested logging line.

Comment: @ZahiE It seems we are missing something. If the line truly is not undefined at any point, the undefined must be coming from somewhere else. I'd suggest using a setter and log each call to the setter to be absolutely sure nothing else is changing the items to undefined. Also, as already suggested, initialize the variable with an empty array or use *ngIf in your template to make sure this is not a timing problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.  The problem was the format of the Typescript interface.  When the API returned the data, it was all set to lowercase variable names and the interface was expecting uppercase on the first letter.  Changing the interface to be camel case works.  The reason why the interface was formatted this way was because of an unorthodox linting rule that has been changed and no longer enforces this.

Answer (score 1):

Actually what happens is, the template is loaded before the subscribe is finished, you can use loading until data is fetched like this

in ts file

```
 this.is_ready = false;
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.items = data.items;
      this.is_ready = true;
    });
```

in html

```
<div *ngIf="is_ready">
 // display data
</div>
```